# C++ "Expression: cannot seek string iterator after end" What Gives?

Tags: c++, string

I was working on a program for a test, and from what I could tell it should work fine, but whenever I tried to test it, I kept getting the same error, and nothing I tried got rid of it.

Here's a screenshot of the error[image]

I have no idea what went wrong, and I couldn't ask for help while the test was on. Now that its finally over, can someone please explain to me what went wrong before I go nuts?!?!?!?

If it helps, here's the code of the file:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cmath>
#include <cctype>
#include <string>

using namespace std;

void rotate_string(string& st, int k, bool right);

int main() {

cout << "Welcome to string rotation!";
string name;
string id;
string name_id;
string phone;

cout << "Enter first name: " << endl;
cin >> name;
cout << "Enter student id: " << endl;
cin >> id;
cout << "Enter phone number (in any format): " << endl;
cin >> phone;
name_id = name + "_" + id;

cout << "name_id before rotation = " << name_id << endl;

cout << "Rotate right for even digit and left for odd digit: " << endl;
for (int i = 0; i < phone.size(); ++i) {
    char num = phone[i];
    if (isdigit(num)) {
        int dig = static_cast<int>(num);
        if ((dig % 2) == 0) {
            rotate_string(name_id, dig, true);
        }
        else {
            rotate_string(name_id, dig, false);
        }
        cout << "digit = " << dig << ", name_id = " << name_id << endl;
        cout << endl;
    }
}
cout << endl;

cout << "Rotated name_id = " << name_id << endl;

cout << "Rotate left for even digit and right for odd digit: " << endl;
for (int i = 0; i < phone.size(); ++i) {
    char num = phone[i];
    if (isdigit(num)) {
        int dig = static_cast<int>(num);
        if ((dig % 2) == 0) {
            rotate_string(name_id, dig, false);
        }
        else {
            rotate_string(name_id, dig, true);
        }
        cout << "digit = " << dig << ", name_id = " << name_id << endl;
        cout << endl;
    }
}
cout << endl;

return 0;

}

void rotate_string(string& st, int k, bool right) {

int n = st.size();
if (right == true) {
    int b = st.size() - k;
    reverse(st.begin(), st.begin() + b);
    reverse(st.begin() + b, st.end());
    reverse(st.begin(), st.end());
}
else {
    reverse(st.begin(), st.begin() + k);
    reverse(st.begin() + k, st.end());
    reverse(st.begin(), st.end());
}

}
```

Things I already tried:

- Putting the function in its own file
- Getting rid of the word string from the method name
- copying all the code into a new project (has worked in the past)
- Tested the method by itself in another projected (where it worked flawlessly)

Comment: *Here's a screenshot of the error* - [Why should I not upload images of code/data/errors?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551)

Comment: `int b = st.size() - k;` - print the value of `b`. In my run with some arbitrary input data I get `-44`. Then you're trying to add `-44` to `std.begin()`... Add assertions on the values of `b` and `k`. [What is a debugger and how can it help me diagnose problems?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25385173/what-is-a-debugger-and-how-can-it-help-me-diagnose-problems) - This is the first thing to try.

Comment: Press `Retry` and it will take you to the line of code with the problem. If it points to msvc code change the "Stack Frame" on the debug toolbar to your code.

Comment: I pressed retry many times and it didn't give me anything. It just terminated the run. and told me nothing.

Comment: Here's a [mre]: https://godbolt.org/z/3r65Mn4Wv -- you can see exactly where it crashes (line 79, or 78 in your code -- I added `<algorithm>` which is a required header). The thing to do next is examine your data. It looks like you're using MS Visual Studio. That has a built-in debugger, which should make this easy. Instead of running your program detached, run it from within the IDE.

Comment: I admit I am highly inexperienced with C++, and even less with the compiler's debugging stuff. But when I looked at the place where I expect error messages to normally show up, it was blank.

Comment: Just print values of `k` and `b` and compare them to `st` size.

Comment: Ok, trying what Evg suggested, it seems the problem is the type casting, which is somehow changing whatever I give it to 50, instead to the right number. Problem with me is that this is the only data type conversion I know about, other the automatic stuff between ints and doubles. Anyone know of another conversion method?

Comment: This doesn’t address the question, but nothing in this code needs the extra stuff that `std::endl` does. `'\n'` ends a line.

Comment: @EmptyStone *is somehow changing whatever I give it to 50*  -- Are you aware that `'1'` is not the same as `1`?

Comment: I only used the type casting because that's the only method of type conversion I was shown in class. Do you know of another?

Comment: In class, you were not shown that to convert a character digit to the actual integer value, you subtract `'0'`?  The reason is that the digits are consecutive in the collating sequence.  Assuming you are using ASCII, `'0'` is 48, `'1'` is 49, etc.  If you look at an ASCII table, you see these values.  In your case, `'2'` is 50, thus subtracting `'0'` will give you the integer 2.

Comment: Yes, this method of conversion never came up in class, or in the digital textbook, zybooks, we were using. Heck, the zybooks only had one part of a chapter on data conversion, and it only showed converting between ints and doubles. I admittedly worked well with the zybooks, learning and understanding the subjects fast, but when deviations appear in other sources and on tests, things tend to fall apart for me.

Comment: *"If it helps, here's the code of the file:"* -- It would help (both us and you) if you reduced the code to a [mre]. Keep it complete enough to compile/run/crash, but get rid of what is not needed to reproduce the error. For example, is outputting `Welcome to string rotation!` really necessary to get the crash? Another example: why risk the user inputting a value that does not lead to the crash? If the crash occurs when the name is `Mike` then force the issue: `string name = "Mike";` and drop the I/O for the name. Same for the ID and phone number. See what other simplifications you can do.

Comment: *"Things I already tried: [...] Getting rid of the word string from the method name"* -- Problems stemming from the name of something would be much rarer if you did not use `using namespace std;`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Adding some very simple debugging to your `rotate_string` function reveals the issue. Do not be afraid to modify your program to explore its behavior. It's one of the simplest forms of debugging that anybody can do.

```cpp
int n = st.size();
if (right == true) {
    int b = st.size() - k;
    cout << "right=true b=" << b << " k=" << k << " n=" << n << endl;
    reverse(st.begin(), st.begin() + b);
    reverse(st.begin() + b, st.end());
    reverse(st.begin(), st.end());
}
else {
    cout << "right=false k=" << k << " n=" << n << endl;
    reverse(st.begin(), st.begin() + k);
    reverse(st.begin() + k, st.end());
    reverse(st.begin(), st.end());
}
```

The first output before your program crashes, with the above modification:

```
right=false k=51 n=14
```

That's using the example input from your screenshot:

```
Mike
454545454
323232323
```

So, even though your string is only 14 characters long, you try to look ahead by 51. Even the error message that you got tells you that you're seeking past the end iterator, and should have given you a clue where to look first, ignoring all other debugging techniques available to find it.

A simple fix for this is to modulo your shift amount by the string size to keep it in bounds:

```cpp
int n = st.size();
if (n == 0) return;   // protect against divide-by-zero
if (k < 0) return;    // protect against negative offset
k %= n;               // ensure k is within string bounds
if (right == true) {
    //...
}
//...
```

That aside, I think part of your confusion arises from the incorrect assumption that the following converts a digit character into its integer equivalent:

```cpp
int dig = static_cast<int>(num);
```

That's not true, and is the reason why you're getting values much larger than 0-9. Your system probably uses the ASCII character set, which encodes digits starting from 48. What you might have intended is this:

```cpp
int dig = num - '0';
```